# How to install pillow on pypy

Tags: pypy, python-imaging-library

How do I install pillow on Windows pypy with png support.

I tried

```
pypy -m pip install --use-wheel pillow
```

This does not find a wheel file (for pypy), so it creates pillow, but does not include png support because it does not find zlib.

I don't want to modify the setup.py, because I want to do this on multiple machines.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install Pillow on pypy3.8 by adding the `ZLIB_ROOT` environment variable.
I'm using vcpkg where the include, lib folders are at `C:\Code\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows`, and I set `ZLIB_ROOT` to `C:\Code\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows as well`.
And then everything works with `pip install Pillow`.

You mentioned you didn't want to edit the `setup.py` file, but actually it was a good idea to read that file, because the answer was located in that file.

Answer (score -1):

How about installing manually zlib.dll in system32? 
http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/index.html