# Pypy and Pillow on Windows?

Tags: python, pip, pypy, python-imaging-library

I have been trying to install the Pillow module 2.6.1 (32 bit) in Pypy (2.7 compatible 32 bit) 2.4.0, on an Windows 7 64 bit machine with no success. Pip 1.5.6 works with Python 2.7.9, and installs Pillow fine, but when I use Pip in the Pypy folder, it throws out [this](http://pastebin.com/PJtZNX8a) (pastebin link). I was wondering if anybody has been able to use Pillow with Pypy successfully, and how you got it working.

Answer (score 2):

Pillow is tested against PyPy on Travis CI but only on Linux.

There are precompiled binaries for most Windows Python versions but not PyPy.

Try the suggestions here (easy_install etc.): http://pillow.readthedocs.org/installation.html#windows-installation and here: [How to install pillow on pypy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737151/how-to-install-pillow-on-pypy)

Otherwise, please can you report this to Pillow?

https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/new